# Custom cocoapod not finding swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a custom Cocoapod to handle all of my networking calls for my iOS application.  The issue that I am having is that some of my files that should be part of my new Cocoapod/framework are not found when I try to reference them in code.

I followed this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift and I successfully created the Cocoapod .xcworkspace project (named: ios-oauth2-rest-template) and added it to bitbucket and created a private PodSpec repo on bitbucket as well (named: KPodSpec) (two separate repos).

I was able to make it through the tutorial but I got stuck on the part 'Using Your New CocoaPod.'  I was able to run the following commands to add the Cocoapod to my PodSpec repo:

```
pod repo add KPodSpecs [Your RWPodSpecs Git URL]
pod repo push KPodSpecs ios-oauth2-rest-template.podspec
```

When I try to use my new pod in an existing project (named: KApp) some of the files that are in my Cocoapod are able to be referenced while others will not autocomplete even after I `import ios_oauth2_rest_template`.

I'm not sure if I'm just missing the framework for `ios-oauth2-rest-template` inside my `KApp` project.  Any help would be much appreciated.

KApp Podfile:

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://bitbucket.org/kpodspecs.git'

target 'KApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for KApp

  target 'KAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'KAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  pod 'LBTAComponents'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'TRON', '~>4.0'

  pod 'ios-oauth2-rest-template', '~> 0.0.1'

end
```

ios-oauth2-rest-template podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

# 1
s.platform = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
s.name = "ios-oauth2-rest-template"
s.summary = "My summary here"
s.requires_arc = true

# 2
s.version = "0.0.1"

# 3
s.license = { :type => "Proprietary", :file => "LICENSE" }

# 4 - Replace with your name and e-mail address
s.author = { "My Name" => "myemail@email.com" }

# 5 - Replace this URL with your own GitHub page's URL (from the address bar)
s.homepage = "https://bitbucket.org/myStuff"

# 6 - Replace this URL with your own Git URL from "Quick Setup"
s.source = { :git => "https://bitbucket.org/myStuff.git",
:tag => "#{s.version}" }

# 7
s.framework = "UIKit"
s.dependency 'Heimdallr', '~> 3.6.1'

# 8
s.source_files = "ios-oauth2-rest-template/**/*.{swift}"

# 9
#s.resources = "RWPickFlavor/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets}"

# 10
# s.swift_version = "4.0"

end
```

ios-oauth2-rest-template Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'ios-oauth2-rest-template' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ios-oauth2-rest-template
    pod 'Heimdallr', '~> 3.6.1'

  target 'ios-oauth2-rest-templateTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance. I have scoured the internet to no avail as to why this could be happening and I am stumped since I don't have that much experience with CocoaPods in the first place.

**UPDATE** 
Here are some screenshots

The Pods section of the KApp, to show some of my classes.  When I try to use `ApplicationUtils` it works just fine and autocompletes, but when I try to use `BaseClass` it cannot seem to find it.
[image: The Pods section of the KApp, to show some of my classes.]

Build phases under settings to show that all 30 files are under compile sources.  The 30 files match the 30 files from the `ios-oauth2-rest-template` Xcode project. The 31st file is `ios-oauth2-rest-template-dummy.m`.
[image: Build phases under settings to show that all 30 files are under compile sources.]

Image showing the folder structure of `ios-oauth2-rest-template` Cocoapod project. 
[image: Image showing the folder structure of ios-oauth2-rest-template]

Comment: Are all the .swift sources put into the `ios-oauth2-rest-template` folder? After the pod install, open your project in Xcode, select `Pods` project from the bottom, select your library name under Targets, then go inside Build Phases / Compile Sources. Can you see all the swift sources there for your pod, or some swift files are missing?

Comment: All of the .swift sources are in the ios-oauth2-rest-template folder.  I have 30 files in the `ios-oauth2-rest-template` Xcode project and when I open `KApp` I have 30 files in the `ios-oauth2-rest-template` folder.  And when I go to Build Phases/Compile Sources I see all of the swift sources there for my pod, yes.

Comment: See the uploaded images above for reference.

Comment: Interesting... another tip: If you're using Xcode's new build system (Xcode > File > Workspace settings), you might have to Clean your project (Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder) and Build it again if you're developing your own pods. Or just try it with the legacy build system.

Comment: I'm using the legacy build system but I just tried with the new build system and nothing different happened. I also cleaned the project and rebuilt it but nada.

Comment: A last tip: Make sure that in your problematic swift files, the classes, structs, enums, etc.. and it's properties/functions are `public`, or `open` to allow them accessible from outside of the pod.

Comment: That was it. Just changing the access control solved it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @balazs630, if you go ahead and post an answer I will accept it over my answer, as the answer to this problem - as you came up with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @balazs630, I was able to solve the problem.  I had to make sure my access control was set to `public` or `open` in order to access them.  Looking back at my code, `ApplicationUtils` was a public class and `BaseClass` had no designation, so it was by default `internal`, which according to the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html):

> Internal access enables entities to be used within any source file
>   from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module.

For anyone with a similar problem, check to make sure your access control is set appropriately.  Here are some sources to familiarize yourself with access control in Swift:

- https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/swift-3-0-1-access-control-9e71d641a56c
- https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

Comment: I have came across this issue, I have used "Public Struct AppConstant" already in my Framework. But., After Pod Install, "AppConstant" - Use of unresolved identifier. Can u pls guide me on this ?